# Round(x,2) have not effect at all?

Tags: r

please download the file in the
https://www.box.com/s/z3tldpdykhppmivfexjl

,save it as  '/tmp/mydata'
and run the following code

```
datafile="/tmp/mydata"
totalsize=file.info(datafile)$size
lines=totalsize/32
con=file(datafile,"rb")
date<-c()
data<-c()
for (i in 1:lines){
    result1<-readBin(con,integer(),n=1,size=4,endian="little")
    date<-c(date,result1)
    result2<-round(readBin(con,double(),n=7,size=4,endian="little"),2)
    data<-c(data,result2)
}
date=data.frame(matrix(date,nrow=lines,ncol=1,byrow=TRUE))
data=data.frame(matrix(round(data,2),nrow=lines,ncol=7,byrow=TRUE))
data=cbind(date,data)
names(data)<-c("date","open","high","low","close","volume","amount","reserved")
data<-data[-c(1:2),]
```

when you finish ,please input `data` in R console,
you can see long digits, 
https://www.box.com/s/lxkbs96vk02p6ekdflbe
[image] 
why `round(data,2)` can not round  2 digits?
it is so strange ,when i write the data into a csv file,open the csv file,i found it has only 2 digits!

```
write.csv(file="/tmp/test",data)
```

Joris Meys say it is bad way to grow vector in for-loops,but i find maybe in my case it is good way to do that ,if not ,how to revise it?let me see the better codes.

Comment: Everything looks rounded to (at most) two digits to me. What's the problem?

Comment: This question is really too localized. Check the FAQ again. And while I'm at it, please stop growing vectors in for-loops immediately, or you wake all the devils in hell! http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: how to revise it not to grow vectors in for-loops?in my case ,maybe it is a good way to do that.

Comment: In your image, it looks to me like everything is in fact rounded to two digits. You may need to read about floating point representations of numbers. (Computers can't represent every number _exactly_ in binary.)

Comment: @DadaLili: It's not a good way to do it. But we can't tell what the right way is without your file: the mydata file you link to is not the data, it's a .png screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the issue about growing the loop, one option is to put everything into a list if you don't know the length of each binary vector read in (as I don't because I have not downloaded your data nor run your code!). Once in a list you can go to a compact form after if each element read in is of the same length, or in this case if all you want is a vector, just `unlist()` each list.

```
datafile <- "/tmp/mydata"
totalsize <- file.info(datafile)$size
lines <- totalsize / 32
con <- file(datafile, "rb")
## allocate storage
date <- data <- vector(mode = "list", length = lines)
## although actually growing lists is not inefficient
for (i in 1:lines){
    ## directly fill in the lists we created using index i to point
    ## to the ith component of each list
    date[[i]] <- readBin(con, integer(), n=1, size=4, endian="little")
    data[[i]] <- round(readBin(con,double(), n=7, size=4, endian="little"), 2)
}
```

At this point you have two lists and if you want them compact-ified into a vector do

```
date <- unlist(date)
data <- unlist(date)
```